# Sorting collection of objects by value inside object

Tags: javascript, sorting, data-structures, ecmascript-6

I have a collection of data that looks like this:

```
const  data = {
    5c80dd171d9e7b3755911818: {
      "_id": "5c80dd171d9e7b3755911818",
      "created_at": "2019-03-07T08:25:11.323Z",
      "description": ""
    }
    5c80dd1b1d9e7b3755911819: {
      "_id": "5c80dd1b1d9e7b3755911819",
      "created_at": "2019-03-07T08:24:11.323Z",
      "description": ""
    }
    5c80dd231d9e7b375591181a: {
      "_id": "5c80dd231d9e7b375591181a",
      "created_at": "2019-03-07T08:27:11.323Z",
      "description": ""
    }
}
```

I've been trying to transform data to an array, sort items inside and then using _keyBy from loadash to create collection once again - but it returns object in mixed order.

**Is there a way that I can sort this collection by the `created_at` value inside an object and get back the same collection and not an array, but sorted ??**

Comment: Possible, but very weird to do (and the sorting order will not be guaranteed in ES5 or lower environments). If you want an ordered collection, best to use an array instead

Comment: This will do the trick: `Object.values(data).sort((a,b)=>a.created_at.localeCompare(b.created_at))`